# Hartree-Fock correction to $e$-$e$ interaction

Tags: condensed-matter, perturbation-theory, electronic-band-theory

The corrections to the energy per electron in a [jellium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jellium) model (uniform distribution of positive ion charge approximation to the regulated long range order ionic array) is given by (in units of Ry) 
$$\frac{E}{N} = \frac{2.21}{(r_s/a_o)^2}  − \frac{0.916}{(r_s/a_o)} +0.0622\ln(r_s/a_o)−0.096+ O(r_s /a_o ). $$
($r_s$ is the radius of a sphere that holds the same volume as one conduction electron and $a_o$ is the Bohr radius, but I don't think is so important to my questions). See e.g. the derivation and this same result in Ashcroft and Mermin P.336.

1. My question is why does the last three terms contain contributions to the kinetic and potential energy? It seems to me that it should only be potential energy since the source of the extra terms comes from the perturbation which is precisely due to the e-e interactions, but I have been told otherwise.
2. My other question is this whole procedure was implemented to better account for the interaction between the electrons in a metal. This expansion above is only valid for $r_s /a_o \ll 1$ and for most metals this value is from 2 to 6. So what is the usefulness of this result then if it does not apply to the very thing it sought out to describe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it's not really appropriate to derivate *quantitative* results about electrons properties in solids, [Jellium model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jellium) still have some interesting *qualitative* features. As you correctly pointed, Jellium still a mean-field theory and so fails about dealing with strongly correlated systems.

Lets remind a few about jellium model. The starting point is the hamiltonian :
$$
\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_{e^-}+\mathcal{H}_{i^+}+\mathcal{H}_{e^-/e^-}+\mathcal{H}_{e^-/i^+}
$$
where $\mathcal{H}_{e^-}$ is the free electrons kinetic energy term, $\mathcal{H}_{i^+}$ is the positive electrostatic ionic background, $\mathcal{H}_{e^-/e^-}$ the electron-electron repulsion term and $\mathcal{H}_{e^-/i^+}$ the interaction between the electrons and ionic background.

By introducing a scale $\gamma$ at which Coulomb interactions between electrons are consistant, which consists basically in taking :
$$
\mathcal{H}_{e^-/e^-}=\lim_{\gamma\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^2}{2}\sum_{i\neq j}\frac{e^{-\gamma|\textbf{x}_i-\textbf{x}_j|}}{|\textbf{x}_i-\textbf{x}_j|}\equiv\lim_{\gamma\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2\Omega}\sum_{\textbf{k},\textbf{p},\textbf{q}}\frac{4\pi e^2}{q^2+\gamma^2}a^\dagger_{\textbf{k}-\textbf{q}}a^\dagger_{\textbf{p}-\textbf{q}}a_{\textbf{p}}a_{\textbf{k}}
$$

Such procedure allows us to get rid of divergences introduced by the $1/r$ decreasing Coulomb interaction. And interestingly, it can be shown that the $\mathcal{H}_{i^+}$ background energy is compensated by the $\textbf{q}=0$ term of $\mathcal{H}_{e^-/e^-}$ **at the thermodynamic limit** ($\Omega\rightarrow+\infty$, where $\Omega$ is the volume of the system). Then, one can end up with :
$$
\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_{e-}+\mathcal{V}=\sum_{\textbf{k}}\frac{\hbar^2\textbf{k}^2}{2m}a^\dagger_{\textbf{k}}a_{\textbf{k}}+\frac{e^2}{2\Omega}\sum_{\textbf{k},\textbf{p},\textbf{q}\neq 0}\frac{4\pi}{q^2}a^\dagger_{\textbf{k}-\textbf{q}}a^\dagger_{\textbf{p}-\textbf{q}}a_{\textbf{p}}a_{\textbf{k}}
$$
Regarding your first question, it is now clear the $\mathcal{V}$ term is the result of the "mixing" (said mutual counterbalance) of various contributions of the initial hamiltonian, namely :
$$
\mathcal{V}=\lim_{\Omega\rightarrow+\infty}\lim_{\gamma\rightarrow 0}\,\mathcal{H}_{i^+}+\mathcal{H}_{e^-/i^+}+\frac{1}{2\Omega}\sum_{\textbf{k},\textbf{p},\textbf{q}}\frac{4\pi e^2}{\gamma^2+q^2}a^\dagger_{\textbf{k}}a^\dagger_{\textbf{p}}a_{\textbf{p}}a_{\textbf{k}}
$$

To obtain the $E/N$ OP's expression, one has just to compute $\frac{\langle F|\mathcal{H}|F\rangle}{N}$ by using a [perturbation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_%28quantum_mechanics%29), where $|F\rangle$ is the Fermi sea :
$$
E=E^{(0)}+E^{(1)}+E^{(2)}+...
$$
Such perturbative expansion is ***valid only if Coulomb interaction is negligible compared to kinetic energy***. Typical kinetic energy scales like :
$$
E_{\text{kin}}\sim E_F\sim n^{2/3}\sim 1/r_s^2\quad\text{where}\;r_s=1/n^3\;\text{with}\;n\;\text{is the density}
$$
$r_s$ can be interpreted as the typical distance between two electrons.
Typical Coulomb energy scales like :
$$
E_{\text{Coulomb}}\sim\frac{e^2}{r_s}\sim\frac{1}{r_s}
$$
Then, it should verify :
$$
\frac{E_{\text{Coulomb}}}{E_{\text{kin}}}\sim\frac{1/r_s}{1/r_s^2}\sim r_s<<1
$$

Regarding your second question, let just plot $E/N$ at first order of perturbation :
[image: jellium]

As you can see, it exhibits a ***negative minimum*** around $\frac{r_s}{a_0}=4.83$. This negative energy minimum actually refers to [metallic bonding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_bonding#Metallic_radius) (attractive interaction), where electrons are somewhat "gluing" ions between them.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I have not studied the Hartree-approximation using your method of annihilation operators so I could not follow your mathematics exactly. (I am following the method in Ashcroft and Mermin (AAM)). I could not understand the part where you say the second term of $\mathcal H$ is the result of mixing of the subsequent terms. Could you maybe describe this part in words or at the level of the notation of AAM? I think the method of AAM is the same you used, just not in the operator formulism. Thanks

Comment: In addition to dolan's answer, I recommend reading first chapter of [Fetter and Walecka's classic many-body book](http://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Theory-Many-Particle-Systems-Physics/dp/0486428273/ "book").
This book provides the best introduction to second quantization method, with thorough and detailed derivations.
By doing so, you can gain acquaintance with second quantization method. Finally, the Jellium model is treated as an example of applying second quantization, at the end of the chapter.

Comment: Actually, I don't really remember how they are doing in AAM. But still, the only thing you need to understand about my notation is just that it's a Fourier analysis of $\mathcal{H}$ and that $\textbf{q}$ refers to the momentum transfert between two electrons interacting through Coulomb interaction. And then, you can see that the $\mathcal{V}$ term is the result of various cancellation of background energy.

Comment: Thanks for the edits.  But how is $\mathcal V$ explicitly got terms in kinetic energy? As far as I can see, there are only contributions from the positive ionic background, electron-ion interaction and electron-electron interaction which all contribute to the potential energy just?

Comment: Yes you're right and actually I don't really understand why you are speaking about kinetic terms in $\mathcal{V}$ since there is none... Kinetic energy is something well separated of $\mathcal{V}$ in jellium model since you are doing a perturbative treatment on $\mathcal{V}$. Such perturbative expansion would be totally messed up if $\mathcal{H}_{e^-}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ where coupled.

Comment: Hmm, my question on my sheet is 'The subsequent terms $0.0622 \ln (r_s/a_o) -0.096 + O(r_s/a_0)$' are collectively known as the correlation energy. Explain why these contain contributions from the kinetic energy as well as the potential energy'?

Comment: Also given that the pertubative expansion is only valid for $r_s/a_o \ll 1$, and most metals have this ratio in the range $2-6$ this means higher order corrections are important in this expansion. For sodium for example $r_s/a_o \approx 4$ which is close to the minimum you mentioned. So this means this value lies in the repulsive end of the graph you drawn and hence the expansion is not valid?

Comment: Hmm ok, the question is quite misleading but I see what is going on : the 1st order correction $E^{(1)}=\langle F|\mathcal{V}|F\rangle$ does not depend on $E^{(0)}=\frac{3N\,E_F}{5}$ which correspond to the mean kinetic energy. But yes $E^{(2)}$ and higher orders does depend on $E^{(0)}$. And be careful : the perturbative expansion is valid for $r_s<<1$ (not $r_s/a_0<<1$), which means that the electron gas you are considering should be quite diluted.

Comment: I see, so is there any way to argue that there must be kinetic energy terms in these additional terms?

Comment: Apart from saying that $E^{(2)}$ and higher orders depend on $E^{(0)}$, I don't think it's really reasonable to say so. Plus, the only reason why it is so is because we used a perturbative treatment on $\mathcal{H}$, so there is no really any physical meaning to extract about this.

Comment: Ok thanks, so the additional terms in the so-called correlation energy term are dependant on the free electron energy and give corrections to this. And there are also corrections to the potential energy to account for corrections in the second term. My last question would be are you sure the expansion is valid for $r_s \ll 1$? I checked AAM and my notes and they both say $r_s/a_o \ll 1$, which is why I was confused about the applicability of this expansion to metals given the typical range of $r_s/a_o$ for them

Comment: See the edit for your last question.

Comment: Thanks, could you describe what the graph you sketched in the answer means physically? For $r_s/a_o \approx 4.8 - 12$ we are in the attractive zone of the potential before the repulsion starts at $r_s/a_o < 4.8$?